# CREATE command denied for user that has GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1142

I am trying to set up a MySQL replication slave, and am having a very difficult time running `LOAD DATA FROM MASTER;`.  Yes, I know it is deprecated, but I am running MySQL 5.1, and that isn't my problem at the moment.

For some reason MySQL keeps telling me the `CREATE` command is denied, but a check of SHOW GRANTS says otherwise.  Check this out:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replicator@%                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA FROM MASTER;
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'replicator'@'localhost' for table 'aggregate'
mysql>
```

What I thought was odd here is that when calling `LOAD DATA FROM MASTER`, it thinks I am `'replicator'@'localhost'`, yet `SHOW GRANTS` says `'replicator'@'%'`.  Just to be safe, I gave the same privs to `'replicator'@'localhost'` as well.

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'replicator'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for replicator@localhost                                                                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'replicator'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFBLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, any thoughts on why this is all messed up?  Yes, I did `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` many times as well.

Thanks in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: The question might be better asked on the ServerFault StackExchange.

Comment: @Treebranch, I thought I was actually posting it there, and after I put it here I realized I had it in the wrong place.  With as many MySQL questions here, I figured it was gray area, so I left it.  I'll let a mod move it if they see fit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would like to suggest the following:

When you login next time run this query:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

If you see two different usernames, you have a weird scenario

This you can find in the MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide (ISBN 0-672-32812-7), Chapter 34 or 35

`USER()` echoes what you attempted to login as

`CURRENT_USER()` echos what mysql ALLOWED YOU to login as.

Try connecting using as replicator using 127.0.0.1 and run the same query.

You may also want to maker sure all necessary columns are present in mysql.user for the version of mysql you are using. If you did not upgrade the mysql.user table (from a migration from MySQL 4 - MySQL 5, or MySQL 5.0 to 5.1) columns in mysql.user could be out of sync.

Comment: This answer does indeed outline the problem I am having and doesn't really explain how or why this problem is happening.  It really doesn't even explain what the problem is...  Why is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 20):

For future searchers, I found that I get this error when using a combination of MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin: if you 'copy SQL' from the tables list, it prepends the schema name on to the table names in the create statement (and in the foreign key commands that may be part of it).

Carefully removing the schema name cured this issue for me.

For example:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schema`.`table1` (
...blah blah blah...

CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `schema`.`table1` (`id` )
...blah blah blah...
```

should be changed to:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
...blah blah blah...

CONSTRAINT `fk_user_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `table1` (`id` )
...blah blah blah...
```

Comment: Great answer. Additionally you don't have to remove a schema statement. Just change schema name in Workbench and Export SQL again. It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me. +1 4 years later.

Comment: Damn! Your answer helped me after 9 years of posting!

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough, simply QUIT-ing the client and reconnecting resolved the issue!  Evidently, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is not enough.

I'd like to hear any comments if you have them on why that is.  I have always heard that `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` will do just that.  Could it have something to do with me originally logging in as `'replicator'@'%'` and then later creating the `'replicator'@'localhost'` account?

In any case, if you have weird permissions issues like this, I guess it is worth trying to reconnect the client.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html says that database privileges take affect next time the `USE` command is executed but clients may have permissions cached.

Answer (score 1):

When using MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard to copy a DB from one server to another, I was presented with the same error message because the new DB name did not match the original one.  The new server automatically places its domain name in front of all DB names creating a mismatch in names.  Therefore when transferring DB `xyz` to the new server `domain`, it called the new DB `domain_xyz` and the above error message occurred for every table creation.

To fix the problem, I manually edited the new DB name after the migration schema was generated, changing it from `xyz` to `doman_xyz`.

Tip-of-the-hat to Camwyn's response that got me looking in this direction.