# SELECT command denied when executing function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, permissions

When I try to select function

```
SELECT myDatabase.myFunction('');
```

I get error that

```
ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'myUser'@'localhost' for table 'myTable'
```

Although user has all permissions

```
mysql> show grants for myUser;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for myUser@%                                                                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD ''                                                                                                                   |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `myDatabase`.* TO 'myUser'@'%'|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and I can also access myTable directly without any problems.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. All function, table, database, user names are ok in case I have misspelled something in this post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254537/create-command-denied-for-user-that-has-grant-all-privileges

Comment: Don't forget that `myuser@localhost` and `myuser@%` are two different accounts, each with its own password and permissions.

Comment: I can access myTable directly without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try a GRANT ALL; Probably FUNCTION Permission is missing